# SQL: Group By with Case Statement for multiple fields

Tags: sql, group-by, case

I am trying to write a GROUP BY clause with a CASE statement so I can conditionally GROUP BY according to the value of the parameter in my query. Here is my query that I am using (significantly shortened) and I keep getting "RVPname is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. And DVPname is invalid and AEname is invalid.

```
SELECT
DVPname, RVPname, AEname, Dealer, Product, Distribution, 

CASE WHEN @LEVEL = 'DVP' THEN DVPname
WHEN @LEVEL = 'RVP' THEN RVPname
WHEN @LEVEL = 'AE' THEN AEname
END AS NAME

..........other code here.....

GROUP BY Product, Distribution,
CASE WHEN @LEVEL = 'RVP' THEN AEname WHEN @LEVEL = 'DVP' THEN RVPname WHEN @LEVEL= 'AE' THEN Dealer END
```

--Does anyone know how to do what I am trying to accomplish. When LEVEL='DVP' I want to GROUP BY RVPname, when LEVEL='RVP' I want to GROUP BY AEname....make sense?

Comment: Does that "other code here" sections contain any aggregates such as sum(), min(), etc?  If so, you have to group by everything in your select clause.  If not, what is the purpose of the group by clause?

Comment: `Group by` case differs from `select` case; they should be identical for this to work.

Comment: The other code only includes calculated fields.

Comment: Again, what is the purpose of the group by clause if you don't have aggregates?

Answer (score 8):

A group by query without aggregates (such as your query) will only be useful for removing duplicates. So your options are to add aggregates for columns in the select clause that aren't in the group by or use the query to remove duplicates.

The following code removes all of the columns (DVPname, RVPname, AEname, Dealer) that are only conditionally in the group by statement (it will hit an error whenever they are not in the group by but are in the select). It also adds the name to the group by so that it can be in the select clause.

```
SELECT
Product, Distribution,
CASE 
    WHEN @LEVEL = 'DVP' THEN DVPname
    WHEN @LEVEL = 'RVP' THEN RVPname
    WHEN @LEVEL = 'AE' THEN AEname
END AS NAME,
CASE 
     WHEN @LEVEL = 'RVP' THEN AEname 
     WHEN @LEVEL = 'DVP' THEN DVPname 
     WHEN @LEVEL= 'AE' THEN Dealer 
END 

..........other code here.....

GROUP BY Product, Distribution, 
CASE 
    WHEN @LEVEL = 'DVP' THEN DVPname
    WHEN @LEVEL = 'RVP' THEN RVPname
    WHEN @LEVEL = 'AE' THEN AEname
END,
CASE 
     WHEN @LEVEL = 'RVP' THEN AEname 
     WHEN @LEVEL = 'DVP' THEN DVPname 
     WHEN @LEVEL= 'AE' THEN Dealer 
END
```

Comment: This will address *RVPname is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause*

Answer (score 1):

You will need to select all of your columns that are not in the `GROUP BY` clause with an aggregate function such as `AVG()` or `SUM()`.  Otherwise, the database doesn't know what to do with the multiple entries that are returned with grouped records.

For example, your select statement should start out with something like this:

```
SELECT
SUM(DVPname), AVG(RVPname),
```

If they are text entries and you know they are all the same, you can also add they to the `GROUP BY` clause.

```
GROUP BY DVPname, RVPname, AEname, Dealer, Product, Distribution
```

In addition, here is a good format for your group by case statement:

```
GROUP BY
CASE WHEN @SortColumn = '0'
THEN [id] END,
CASE WHEN @SortColumn = '1'
THEN [name] END;
```

Comment: So you will have either `GROUP BY null, name` or `GROUP BY id, null`, right?

Comment: It would either by `GROUP BY [id]` or `GROUP BY [name]`.  Also, you could combine all of those into something like `GROUP BY  DVPname, RVPname, AEname, Dealer, Product, Distribution, CASE WHEN @SortColumn = '0' THEN [id] END, CASE WHEN @SortColumn = '1' THEN [name] END;`

Comment: Nope. You have not used `ELSE` but instead listed two `CASE` statements, separated by a comma.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want conditional `group by` then I would suggest using a subquery:

```
select name, . ..
from (select (CASE WHEN @LEVEL = 'DVP' THEN DVPname
                   WHEN @LEVEL = 'RVP' THEN RVPname
                   WHEN @LEVEL = 'AE' THEN AEname
              END
             ) AS NAME, t.*
      from t
     ) t
group by name;
```

However, you lose all the other fields that you want.  In most databases, you can't include columns in the `select` unless they are aggregated or in the `group by` clause.  Here is an alternative for getting an arbitrary value from the columns:

```
SELECT min(DVPname), min(RVPname), min(AEname), min(Dealer), min(Product),
       min(Distribution),
       . . .
from (select (CASE WHEN @LEVEL = 'DVP' THEN DVPname
                   WHEN @LEVEL = 'RVP' THEN RVPname
                   WHEN @LEVEL = 'AE' THEN AEname
              END
             ) AS NAME, t.*
      from t
     ) t
group by name;
```

This returns the min values for the columns.

Answer (score 0):

I know of two methods: GROUP BY (Case statement 1, Case statement 2) and subquery. I determine how many rows each method will take and then base my process on that.

ex. (group by):

```
    SELECT
        CASE
            WHEN (situation A)
            THEN (result A)
            WHEN (situation B)
            THEN (result B)
        END column1,
        CASE
            WHEN (situation C)
            THEN (result C)
            WHEN (situation D)
            THEN (result D)
        END column2,
        SUM(AMOUNT) as TotalAMOUNT
    FROM aTable
    GROUP BY 
        CASE
            WHEN (situation A)
            THEN (result A)
            WHEN (situation B)
            THEN (result B)
        END,
        CASE
            WHEN (situation C)
            THEN (result C)
            WHEN (situation D)
            THEN (result D)
        END
```

ex. (Subquery)

```
    SELECT
        Column1,
        Column2,
        SUM(AMOUNT) as TotalAMOUNT
    FROM
        (
        SELECT
            CASE
                WHEN (situation A)
                THEN (result A)
                WHEN (situation B)
                THEN (result B)
            END column1,
            CASE
                WHEN (situation C)
                THEN (result C)
                WHEN (situation D)
                THEN (result D)
            END column2,
            AMOUNT
        FROM aTable
        )CaseTable
    GROUP BY Column1, Column2
    ORDER BY Column1 asc, SUM(AMOUNT)
```

I think important to remember is that you can't contain additional details beyond what you're grouping together.  In the above two examples, the results of your query are grouped by the variable you specify.  You could also tack on some type of status depending on your variable, and then roll it up by the additional column, and choose not to display the final column in the rollup.